# Annihilator polynomial and the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Let

$$L(f(t)) = F(s)=N(s)/M(s)$$

be the Laplace Transform of a certain (exponential-bounded) function, $N(s)$ and $M(s)$ being minimal polynomials.

Is it true that the operator $M(D)$ always annihilates $f(t)$ (i.e., $M(D)f(t) = 0$, where $D=d/dt$)?

Does this fact generalize to some more general function types?

I'll illustrate this with several examples:

1) $f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k t^k, c_k$ are real parameters, $n$ is a natural number. In this case, $F(s)= pol_n(s)/s^{n+1}$, where $pol_n(s)$ is a polynomial in $s$ of degree $n$. $M(s)=s^{n+1}$, so $M(D)=D^{n+1}$, which clearly annihilates $f(t)$.

2) $f(t) = e^{at}, a$ is a real parameter. In this case, $F(s)=1/(s-a)$. $M(s)=s-a$, so $M(D)=D-a$, which clearly annihilates $f(t)$.

3) $f(t) = c_1\sin(wt) + c_2\cos(wt)$, where $w, c_1$ and $c_2$ are real parameters. In this case, $F(s)= (c_1w + c_2s)/(s^2+w^2)$. $M(s)=s^2+w^2$, so $M(D)=D^2+w^2$, which clearly annihilates $f(t)$.

You could actually take advantage of several theorems about the Laplace Transform (e.g. Shift on the $s$-plane) to calculate the annihilator of more complex functions:

4) $f(t) = c_1e^{at}\sin(wt) + c_2e^{at}\cos(wt)$, where $a, w, c_1$ and $c_2$ are real parameters. In this case, $F(s)= (c_1w + c_2(s-a))/((s-a)^2+w^2)$. $M(s)=(s-a)^2+w^2$, so $M(D)=(D-a)^2+w^2$, which annihilates $f(t)$.

5) $f(t) = c_1t\sin(wt) + c_2t\cos(wt)$, where $w, c_1$ and $c_2$ are real parameters. In this case, $F(s)= (2c_1ws + c_2(s^2-w^2))/(s^2+w^2)^2$. $M(s)=(s^2+w^2)^2$, so $M(D)=(D^2+w^2)^2$, which annihilates $f(t)$.

6) $f(t) = c_1t^ne^{at}$, where $a, c_1$ are real parameters and $n$ is a natural number. In this case, $F(s)= c_1n!/(s-a)^{n+1}$. $M(s)=(s-a)^{n+1}$, so $M(D)=(D-a)^{n+1}$, which annihilates $f(t)$.

Finally, you could sum up some of the previous results to get the following:

7) $f(t) = (\sum_{k=0}^n c_k t^k)e^{at}\sin(wt) + (\sum_{k=0}^n d_k t^k)e^{at}\cos(wt)$, where $a, w, c_k$ and $d_k$ are real parameters. In this case, $M(D)=((D-a)^2+w^2)^{n+1}$, which annihilates $f(t)$.

What about $f(t)= \sqrt{t}$, for which $F(s)=\sqrt{\pi}/(2s^{3/2})$?

Answer (score 0):

- If $M(x) = \sum_{n=0}^m c_n x^n$ then $M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^m c_n \frac{d^n}{dt^n} f(t)$ and $$\mathcal{L}[M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t)](s) = \sum_{n=0}^m c_n \mathcal{L}[\frac{d^n}{dt^n} f(t)](s) = \sum_{n=0}^m c_n  s^n F(s)=M(s) F(s)$$ 
  If $M(s) F(s)=\sum_{k=0}^K a_k s^k$  is a polynomial then $$M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t)   =\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\sum_{k=0}^K a_k s^k](t) = \sum_{k=0}^K a_k \delta^{(k)}(t)$$ where $\delta^{(k)}(t)$ is the **distributional derivative of the Dirac delta distribution** and the $k+1$-th derivative of $ 1_{t > 0}$ or $-1_{t < 0}$ depending on the domain of convergence.

  Thus $M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t) = 0$ only for $t \ne 0$ and around $t= 0$ it is not function.
- Does it generalize ? Well this is the convolution theorem for the Fourier/Laplace transform of distributions.

Comment: You're not considering that the operator $M(D)$ is actually the denominator of the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ (expressed in minimal polynomials). This is the core of the question. Please analyze the examples I added.

Comment: @Alfonso ?? I did when assuming $M(s)F(s)$ is a polynomial. Do you understand why $M(\frac{d}{dt})f$ is not $0$ everywhere ? (try with $f(t) = 1_{t > 0}, F(s) = \frac{1}s, M(s) = s$ then $M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t) = f'(t) =\delta(t)$ the Dirac delta distribution)

Comment: Hi @Reuns, thank you for your comments. I do understand your approach. I considered in the first place the one-sided Laplace Transform and I make the assumption that the function $f$ has domain from $-\inf$ to $+\inf$, avoiding the derivation of the step function in the calculation of $M(D)f(t)$. So, in the second example, I consider really $f(x) = e^{at}$ instead of $f(x) = e^{at}1_{t > 0}$.

Comment: @Alfonso Sorry what you write doesn't mean anything. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{at} e^{-st}dt$ diverges for every $s$. As I wrote it is true that $M(\frac{d}{dt}) f(t)= 0$ for $t\ne 0$, but in the neighborhood of $0$ it is a non-zero distribution (distributional derivatives of the Dirac delta) this is why its Laplace transform is a non-zero polynomial in $s$.